# Suitable parameters to reshape datasets

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, reshape

I am learning about deep learning and tensorflow in this website https://pythonprogramming.net/loading-custom-data-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/

I want to know is there any rule of thumb to reshape the array of the datasets?

```
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
```

For instance, from the code snippet above, I don't understand the meaning of the numbers passed to function reshape(). How to know the suitable numbers to be passed to the function?

Answer (score 0):

The 4 dimensions in

```
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
```

are the following:

dimension 0: images in the batch

dimension 1: rows

dimension 2: columns

dimension 3: number of channels in image

Since this is grayscale, the image has 1 channel, so the last number is 1 (if it was RGB image, the last number would have been 3, representing the 3 channels in RGB).

Dimensions 1 and 2 are the numbers of rows and columns in every image, which in your case is just `IMG_SIZE`. Dimension 0 is the batch size. You can specify there the number if you knowthe batch size, or you can leave it as -1, and it will be determined uniquely because all the other sizes (dimensions 1,2,3) are provided.

Comment: I see.
So the array is a 4 dimensional array?
Do each dimension 0 and dimension 3 have "names"?
Like for dimension 1 it is called row 
and for dimension 2 it is called column.
I know in matlab the third dimension is called depth if not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, dimension 0 is basically batch size, dimension 3 is number of channels

Comment: OK. Thank you for the explanation.